# How to persist Sensor telemetry data into cold storage such as big data storage or cosmosdb

Tags: azure-digital-twins

Azure digital twin gives example of using Time Series Insights. Looking for steps how to persist  Sensor telemetry data into cold storage such as  big data storage or cosmosdb for later retrieval for the business application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are currently implementing such a system and I made a few tests, among which create an endpoint of type "Event Hub" (through the API) and then configuring the "Capture" feature to put the collected data into AVRO files in a Data Lake. This works but may not be the most ideal solution for what we need so I'll explore streaming data from the IoT Hub to a SQL DB... Now I need to access that IoT Hub that was created through the API and is not available in the Azure Portal... Will keep you posted.

Comment: Thanks, Fred. Look forward. I feel that Space graph model should have provision to define cold storage path. So later this space graph model will be used to get the sensor and associated historical data.

Comment: You could also make a feature request here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/916621-azure-digital-twins

Comment: Thanks. Requested the feature

Answer (score 2):

For future reference linking the [Azure Digital Twins User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/916621-azure-digital-twins/suggestions/35997949-enhance-the-current-space-graph-model-of-digital-t) entry

Alina Stanciu commented  ·  December 20, 2018 12:53 PM  ·

Azure Digital Twins events and messages could be routed to Azure Event Hubs, Azure Service Bus topics, or Azure Event Grid for further processing.

For warm analytics, you could send the data to an Event Hub and from there to Azure Time Series Insights (TSI). TSI added recently cold storage as well (they are public preview for cold storage).

If you need more advanced analytics on cold storage, you can forward the data from Event Hub to Azure Data Lake (ADL). Our customers are storing today warm and cold data from sensor & spaces into TSI and ADL. We are looking into integrating our graph modeling with TSI and ADL so modeling will be defined in one place Digital Twins and will be discovered and recognized in downstream services.

Answer (score 0):

I used a custom Edge Module routing messages to IoT Hub, then set up a Stream Analytics Job with IoT hub as input and an azure sql instance as the output. It was pretty painless.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-manage-job

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-stream-analytics-query-patterns#query-example-send-data-to-multiple-outputs